# Manyind package: can I customise the index?

Tags: manyind

With *imakeidx* I can give the index the aspect I want using a .ist file. It seems like I can’t do it with *manyind*. I would like to remove the comma in the index after each entry and if possible to have three columns instead of two in each page. Is there a way to do that? Looking at the .sty file I’m able to put dots after each entry but I don’t know if it’s possible to do these other things.

Edit: I can write an MWE but it seems the package manyind is not implemented. It can be found in https://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyind

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{manyind}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
I write something \setindex{main}\index{Something}
I write another thing \setindex{Second}\index{Another thing}

\printindex
\setindex{Second}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete but yet minimal code example that shows explains your problem, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `manyind`? I may be biased, but…

Comment: If I try to print more than one index with other packages, it prints only the first. With manyind I don’t have this problem, but it lacks of customisation...

Comment: The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) supports multiple indexes, each of which can be configured by a different `.ist` file.